# print first four columns but afterwards every forth column

Tags: awk

I have a big table. I want to keep the first four columns but afterwards only print every forth column.

I tried

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{
                   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                        if(i<=4)
                            print $0
                         else if(i>4 && (i%4)==0)
                             print $i
                    }
}'
```

Comment: change `print $0` to `print $i` ?

Comment: works but print everything horizontally in one column!

Comment: columns are vertical. rows are horizontal. Which do you want? Posting some sample input and expected output is always extremely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat sample.csv 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat test.awk 
BEGIN{
FS=",";
OFS="\t"
}
{   
    str = "";
    counter = 0;
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        if(i <= 3 || i % 4 == 0){
            counter += 1
            if(counter < 3 + NF/4 - 1){
                str = str $i OFS
            }else{
                str = str $i
            }
        }
    };
    print str
}
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ awk -f test.awk sample.csv
1   2   3   4   8   12
1   2   3   4   8   12  16
1   2   3   4   8   12
```

I was using commas as field separator, if your field separator is whitespace, just remove FS that in the BEGIN clause.

Comment: I'd go with `if ( i<=4 || i%4 == 0 )`, it's a little shorter and lets you skip the `else` clause.

Comment: To consider for the "flaw" - you could calculate the final field to print with something like `final_fld=NF-(NF%4)` and then use it to cap the loop and when constructing `str` with a ternary operator to decide when to append `OFS`.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing @haifzhan's input file and using `;`s instead of tabs in the output so you can see where the OFSs occur:

```
$ cat file
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=";" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( i<5 || !(i%4) ) {
            printf "%s%s", (i>1?OFS:""), $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1;2;3;4;8;12
1;2;3;4;8;12;16
1;2;3;4;8;12
```

Just change the settings of FS and OFS in the BEGIN section to be your real input and desired output field separators.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid much test in script try:

```
awk -F, '{
printf "%s\t%s\t%s",$1,$2,$3
for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=4)
    printf "\t%s",$i
print ""
          }' file
```